# How is double spending prevented or checked using Proof-of-stake consensus mechanism?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus

Recently I've been reading about this new blockchain network called Aptos( a Layer-1 Blockchain) which in it's mechanism explains how they let run transactions parallel to reduce latency. Now I wonder how do they ensure that there is no double Spending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptos uses Move, a programming language that focuses on scarcity and access control. Scarcity imposes limit on asset creation to prevent double-spending, while access control manages ownership and privileges. Move uses a concept in mathematics called linear logic, which dictates that resources can only be moved between program storage locations, but never copied or discarded, thus maximizing security without adding computational complications to reduce gas fees.

Source: https://boxmining.com/aptos-vs-sui/